# images on Gatsby.js site won't display on GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am having trouble getting images to display on github pages. I am using a repository based page. I have added in a simple img tag with in the JSX and tried using the method described in the Gatsby documentation. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Here is the code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import AnchorLink from 'react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll';
import { ThemeContext } from 'providers/ThemeProvider';
import { Header } from 'components/theme';
import { Container, Button } from 'components/common';
import dev from 'assets/illustrations/dev.svg';
import { Wrapper, IntroWrapper, Details, Thumbnail } from './styles';
import { withPrefix } from 'gatsby'

import HeadShotPlaceHolder from 'assets/images/HeadShotPlaceHolder.jpeg'

export const Intro = () => {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  console.log(HeadShotPlaceHolder)

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Header />
      <IntroWrapper as={Container}>
        <Details theme={theme}>
          {/* <h1>Hi There!</h1> */}
          <h1>Pamela Welch</h1>
          {/* <h4>I’m John and I’m a JAMStack engineer!</h4> */}
          <h4>A proven professional with extensive experience in all facets of communication and marketing.</h4>
          <Button as={AnchorLink} href="#contact">
            Hire me
          </Button>
        </Details>
        <Thumbnail>
          
          {/* This is where the image tag giving me the problem is */}
          <img src={ withPrefix(HeadShotPlaceHolder) } alt="I’m John and I’m a JAMStack engineer!" />

        </Thumbnail>
      </IntroWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

and here is the result

[Image Link Broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzsNo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, your image has its path prefixed. However, to make it effective you need to run the following snippet in the deploy command:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"
  }
}
```

Note the `--prefix-paths` flag.

More information in [How Gatsby Works in GitHub Pages.](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was able to help me find a naming issue in my site. I kept getting 404 errors on content that was supposed to load but this got me to check the "src" attributes on my images and see that it was all being named incorrectly. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to help. If the issue has been solved please close the topic.